# past before past

Tags: past-perfect

https://www.nytimes.com/2019/01/18/us/politics/pelosi-donald-trump-cancel-travel.html

> Mr. Trump **asked** on Twitter before Ms. Pelosi’s office had announced
>   the postponement.

I think past before past should be in past perfect tense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When "before" or "after" is used in a sentence past perfect is not necessary because these words make the order of events clear. In your example it is understood Trump's asking preceded Pelosi's announcement.